# Storage of references in stack memory

Tags: java

How is the **reference it self** are store in stack memory. For example suppose,

```
A a = new A();
```

This `a` should also be stored in memory and should has a memory address right?

If i explain more, If we print `System.out.println(a)` it will print the memory address of "object A". But how can i print the memory address of reference `a`?

Correction: If we print `System.out.println(a)` it will print the hash code of "object A" not the memory address of Object A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can i print the memory address of reference a?

You cannot, quite simply. The JVM specification doesn't define the underlying properties of the stack in any way whatsoever, and going strictly by the specification, there is no guarantee that it even has a memory address. In practice, on current implementations, of course, it does, but the specification leaves that undefined, and thus Java has no interface for examining the memory layout of the stack.

Furthermore, it should be noted that a stack variable is, in fact, not guaranteed to have a memory address at all. It is not uncommon for them to reside entirely in registers and never be flushed to memory.

However, it should also be mentioned that, unlike what you say, `System.out.println(a)` will *not* print the address of the object referred to by `a`. What it prints is also undefined by the specification, but Oracle's implementation prints the identity hash code of `a`, not its address. The address of `a` is not even guaranteed to be constant over its lifetime, as the GC may move it around.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is faulty; `System.out.println(a);` will print the address of a handle to the object, not the objcet itself:

> In some of Oracle’s implementations of the Java Virtual Machine, a
>   reference to a class instance is a pointer to a handle that is itself
>   a pair of pointers: one to a table containing the methods of the
>   object and a pointer to the Class object that represents the type of
>   the object, and the other to the memory allocated from the heap for
>   the object data.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.7)

As the JVM "reserves the right" to move things about in memory during execution, a reference to the JVM object itself wouldn't be guaranteed to be usable for anything. In fact, when Java performs garbage collection, it makes no guarantee of placing forwarding pointers to the new address of live objects, making it likely that a garbage collection would render the JVM address (even if you *could* obtain it) useless.

See http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2003fa/lectures/sec24.htm for a simplified explanation about how garbage collection works.

Comment: I didnt understand the meaning of "address of a handle to the object".  As you mentioned even "a" cosider as pointer, pointer it self should store in memory know. What i understood was pointer "a" has the value as the hashcode of Object A

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(a)` prints `a.hashCode()` (unless `a.toString()` is overriden) which need not be the address of a.